# Alignment of exponential numbers with non-exponential number

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, siunitx

I would like to align non-exponential and exponential number at their decimal point in a table.
I tried

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}    
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    Variable  & Coefficient Weight                              \\
    \midrule
    A         & \tablenum[table-format = 3.4]{0.0018}           \\
    B         & \tablenum[table-format=1.4e2]{-6.0113E-4}       \\ 
    C         & \tablenum[table-format = 3.4]{0.4365}           \\
    D         & \tablenum[table-format = 3.4]{1.2386}           \\
    E         & \tablenum[table-format = 3.4]{-0.3071}          \\
    \bottomrule     
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

which doesn't create the desired alignment for the exponential number. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Erh, you are not suppose to use `\tablenum` in all cells in the column. Just configure the entire column with the `-1.4e-1` format.

Comment: `\tablenum` can be used if you have a few items in a column that use a different formatting than the overall layout of the column.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isn't this what you want

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}    
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=-1.4e-1]}
    \toprule
    Variable  & {Coefficient Weight}                              \\
    \midrule
    A         & 0.0018           \\
    B         & -6.0113E-4       \\ 
    C         & 0.4365           \\
    D         & 1.2386           \\
    E         & -0.3071          \\
    \bottomrule     
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Drat: I'd got all of that written then someone needed me for 2 minutes :-)

Comment: Perfect solution and super fast response! Thank you both :)

Comment: @JosephWright After compiling the example, I saw daleif's comment.